# Not able to get the publisher name for a MS Teams App through Graph API

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to get the publisher name for Teams App and I'm using the below graph API end point:-

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/appCatalogs/teamsApps?$expand=appDefinitions&$filter=id eq 'GUID-xxxxxxxxx'

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#appCatalogs/teamsApps(appDefinitions())",
"value": [
    {
        "id": "{GUID-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}",
        "externalId": null,
        "displayName": "OneNote",
        "distributionMethod": "store",
        "appDefinitions@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#appCatalogs/teamsApps(GUID-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')/appDefinitions",
        "appDefinitions": [
            {
                "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "teamsAppId": "GUID-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "displayName": "OneNote",
                "version": "1.0.0",
                "publishingState": "published",
                "shortDescription": "Use OneNote notebooks to collaborate on digital content with your team.",
                "description": "Use OneNote notebooks to collaborate on digital content and share it with your team.",
                "lastModifiedDateTime": null,
                "createdBy": null
            }
        ]
    }
    ]
}
```

In the above response created by is null and also there is no publisher name field. Not able to find in Microsoft docs for graph API. Any clues would be appreciated. PowerShell/PowerAutomate/GraphAPI anything route can be done.

[image]

The image of how it shows in the MS Teams App.

Comment: Hello, We have raised a bug internally. Concerned team is looking into it. We will let you know the updates.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We are able to repro this at our end and we have raised a bug internally. We do not have an ETA to share but we will share updates on this thread.

Comment: Thanks @Hunaid will be waiting for the update!

Comment: This is feature ask which hasn't implemented yet. To achieve your requirements, we recommend you give your feedback in Teams [UserVoice](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472).